# Connect a EC2 instance from a VPC to instance in EC2-Classic

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have a machine which is in a VPC. I have a server which wants to talk to admin server (tcp port) on an instance which is EC2-Classic.

I have created a link to connect this EC2-Classic to VPN.

Inbound port to which I am connecting to this instance (ec2-classic) is opened.

But still no luck.

Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for coming back late to this , but there were issues in my hosts file . 
Following link works good to link your VPC with EC2-classic .

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/classiclink-private-communication-between-classic-ec2-instances-vpc-resources/

If you want to link 2 VPC , use VPC peering .

Thanks ,
Piyush

Answer (score 0):

I would start to have a look at

- EC2 Classic Security Groups (Inbound traffic)
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#ec2-classic-security-groups
- your VPC routing tables to ensure you correctly route traffic from VPC to EC2
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html#route-tables-classiclink